# Can I try before I buy on Playstation?

Tags: ps4

Is it possible to try games before I buy them, on Playstation? Specifically Playstation 4? Googling didn't produce results, suprisingly...

(e.g. On PC, if you install games via Origin you can get Origin Access and then try the game before you buy..)

Comment: I'm sure there are demos available for most games on PS4.

Comment: @TimmyJim not most games, actually. Very few games have trials these days. And the hour free trial seems to not be on PS4, but it was a feature on PS3 for PS+ subscribers.

Comment: You could try your local gamestore. I know mine let's you try out games on the consoles they have hooked up in the store (XBOX One, Wii U and PS4 among them). Naturally they don't let you hang around the entire day, but generally long enough to get a good idea of whether you want to buy it or not and you can easily ask any questions you have (though they might not always have an answer). All depends on if the gamestore allows it though.

Answer (score 2):

Unless there is a specific listed demo for a game, there is currently no way to just trial any game on the store.

Answer (score 0):

There are certain sites for ex. [gameflab.com](http://gameflab.com) which offer games to be rented for 15 or 30 days. You could rent games of your choice from these sites for a meagre amount and then if you like the game, then you could go ahead and purchase it. Hope it helped your question.

Comment: Why was my answer marked as not useful? Did I write something wrong?